# config.js doesn't work for CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have the following in my `config.js` for CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.toolbar =
    [
        [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic' ]
    ];
    // config.toolbar_Basic =
    // [
    //     [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic' ]
    // ];
    // config.toolbar = 'Basic';
}
```

The editor is still showing with all the options in the toolbar.

It is also loading the JS files in the right order:

```
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/init.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/config.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I am not sure what is happening here. Any thoughts?

Also important to note that I tried the alternative way of declaring that `Basic` toolbar (see the commented out code in the snippet above) and it didn't work either.

After every change, I restart my server.

Comment: Can you post a URL / [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your issue?

Comment: Not quite sure how to require ckeditor on jsFiddle. Also...not sure if the issue is related to Rails or just JS. I suspect it may be more of a Rails issue and not a JS issue. i.e. Rails pipeline is having some issues...or something of that nature. But, I can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you load you ckeditor in place of the textarea? Maybe the toolbar is overridden there.

Comment: bro could you please take a look at my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397155/ckedtior-appearance-not-show-fully-in-drupal-7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `config.js` file looks OK (both versions of it).

What may be wrong is how you load CKEditor. First of all - you don't need to load config.js - CKEditor will do that. Second, what's in the `init.js` file?

Have you cleared a cache in your browser? On some it can be really hard to do that automatically.

Comment: I am using the ckeditor gem in Rails, so it automatically loads those files for me. On the gem page - https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor - it says I should explicitly load `ckeditor/init` (which I do). I have not cleared a cache in my browser, but I will try that.

Comment: Ok I just tried loading my page in an Incognito Window (i.e. a non-cached version) and the editor still has all of the stuff I don't want to see.

Comment: Have you checked browser JS console? If there's no error I don't know what's wrong. Perhaps it's something related to Galetahub's CKEditor gem. Maybe it requires you to configure it in different way. One more thing that you can check is in network tab in dev toolbar in Chrome, when `config.js` is loaded and what's inside. Also, ensure that it isn't loaded twice.

Comment: How do you load you ckeditor in place of the textarea? Maybe the toolbar is overridden there.

Comment: @jeroenk Perfect...you are a GENIUS. That was it. I didn't realize that in the form helper in Rails, I was specifying the `full` toolbar. I changed that to `Basic` and now it works perfectly. THANKS MUCH! If you add that as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Download CKEditor 3.2.1 here:  http://ckeditor.com/download

Extract the downloaded .tar.gz file.

Copy the contents of the ckeditor folder into /sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor

At this point you may want to edit the available toolbar options removing any unnecessary items. In most cases, I prefer the following configuration as it allows maximum fanciness while minimizing the types of markup which could override the site's styling

edit /sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js

Create a new toolbar by adding the following configuration to ckeditor.config.js:

**

```
config.toolbar_DrupalCustom = [
      ['Source'],
      ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
      ['Undo','Redo','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
      ['Image','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar'],
      ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
      ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Blockquote'],
      ['Link','Unlink','Anchor','LinkToNode', 'LinkToMenu'],      
      ['Format','Font','FontSize'],
      ['TextColor','BGColor'],
      ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks'],
      ['DrupalBreak', 'DrupalPageBreak']
     ];
```

**
You can now select this option within the CKEditor Appearance section at /admin/settings/ckeditor/edit/Advanced

Answer (score 1):

I too had problems with CKEditor and the "caching" issue. Cleared cache, loaded a custom config file... and timestamps...

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Problem-with-config.js-not-updating

Nothing worked. Then i simply added it as options when instantiating the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'controls_' + int_control_cnt + '_label_text' ,
            {
            toolbar: [
                ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'TextColor', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
                ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']
            ]
            });
```

This did the trick

Answer (score 0):

use only:
`<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`

and be sure to clear your browser cache!

Comment: I try to solve this problem and find this question without heplful advice. But I find decision later. If there were the right decision, it would make my life easier.